# Two dialogs in one onCreateDialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker

Hello I'm trying to put date and time pickers in one class.
Everything works fine when i call time picker but unfortunately if I click date calling button the time picker is also appears.

here is my code:

```
package com.example.aib.restauwacja;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateAndTimePicker extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edit;

    Button dateBtn;
    Button timeBtn;
    Button reserveBtn;

    int year_x, mounth_x, day_x;
    int hour_x, minute_x;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.making_reservation);
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mounth_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDateOnButtonClick();
        showTimeOnButtonClick();
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
        reserveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makeReservationButton);
        reserveBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String amount = edit.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, edit.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public void showDateOnButtonClick() {
        dateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.datePickerButton);

        dateBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            year_x = year;
            mounth_x = monthOfYear + 1;
            day_x = dayOfMonth;
            Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, day_x + "/" + mounth_x + "/" + year_x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public void showTimeOnButtonClick() {
        timeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.timePickerButton);
        timeBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID)
            return new TimePickerDialog(DateAndTimePicker.this, tpickerListener, hour_x, minute_x, true);
        else if (id == DATE_DIALOG_ID)
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, year_x, mounth_x, day_x);
        return null;
    }

    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tpickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            hour_x = hourOfDay;
            minute_x = minute;
            Toast.makeText(DateAndTimePicker.this, hour_x + ":" + minute_x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code of showDialog() method.

Comment: public void showDateOnButtonClick()
{
    dateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.datePickerButton);

    dateBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

                }
            }
    );
}

Comment: i am asking the implementation of the showDialog() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give different id's for DATE_DIALOG_ID and TIME_DIALOG_ID.
check these fields once.

```
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different id of  DATE_DIALOG_ID and TIME_DIALOG_ID;